# XPath expression /node()[1] selects more than the first node?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, predicate

I have a document `doc.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- This is the first top-level node -->
<!-- This is the second top-level node -->
<ThirdNode/>
<!-- This is the fourth top-level node -->
```

I'd like to select the first top-level node from the document, in `firstnode.xsl`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/node()[1]">First</xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When I run `xsltproc firstnode.xsl doc.xml`, I get:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
FirstFirst<ThirdNode/><!-- This is the fourth top-level node -->
```

… instead of the expected output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
First
<!-- This is the second top-level node -->
<ThirdNode/>
<!-- This is the fourth top-level node -->
```

Why does the `/node()[1]` selector match more than just the first comment?  How can I select the first node of the document (regardless of whether it is a comment, element, or whatever)?

Comment: try with `(/node())[1]`

Comment: @eLRuLL I did try that, and got `xsltCompilePattern : failed to compile '(/node())[1]'`

Comment: For the record: xsltproc was compiled against libxml 20902, libxslt 10128 and libexslt 817;
libxslt 10128 was compiled against libxml 20902;
libexslt 817 was compiled against libxml 20902

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have managed to reproduce your problem using the `libxlt` processor, but not with `Xalan` or `Saxon` - which leads me to conclude that this is non-conforming behavior.

Changing the match pattern to:

```
<xsl:template match="node()[not(parent::*)][1]">
```

seems to bypass the issue.

---

Surprisingly, even adding a bogus condition to your original expression, such as:

```
<xsl:template match="/node()[not(0)][1]">
```

or even:

```
<xsl:template match="/node()[1][1]">
```

also works, so this is clearly a bug.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I did correctly understand your question. However, I tried to reproduce your question and the result was this:

**Input.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<First>
  <Second>
    <ThirdNode/>      
    <Fourth />
  </Second>
</First>
```

**Processing.xslt**:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="/node()[1]">First1
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
First1

  <Second>
    <ThirdNode/>      
    <Fourth/>
  </Second>
```

Maybe this helps you in some way.